# React Page keeps crashing when accessing component State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I don't exactly know what I'm doing, but I'm trying to achieve some sort of side-bar menu which will switch out content in a `<main>` tag when I click menu buttons. But the issue is that when I read my initial page's content via the `MainMenu`'s `state`, the page just stalls until it eventually tells me that React has crashed.

The `main` tag:

```
<main
    className={classNames(classes.content)}
>
    <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
    { this.state.content }
    { this.state.modal }
</main>
```

The initial State:

```
state = {
    open: false,
    modal: <GameDialog
        dialogTitle={"Title"}
        dialogContentText={"Description"}
        open={false}
    />,
    content: [
        <div key={Math.random()}>Still need to write something here</div>,
        <ComplexCardGrid
            key={Math.random()}
            gridHeader="Featured Projects"
            category="featured"
            featured={true}
        />
    ]
};
```

I have a `handleClick` function that doesn't do anything even though it's used in my menu:

```
handleClick = id => {
    let newContent = [];
    switch (id) {
        case MainMenuConstants.COMMERCIAL:
            newContent.push(
                <ComplexCardGrid
                    key={Math.random()}
                    gridHeader="Commercial Projects"
                    category="commercial"
                />
            );
            break;

        ...

        case MainMenuConstants.CONTACT:
        case MainMenuConstants.ABOUT:
        case MainMenuConstants.HOME:
        default:
            newContent.push(
                <div>Still need to write something here</div>
            );
            newContent.push(
                <ComplexCardGrid
                    key={Math.random()}
                    gridHeader="Featured Projects"
                    category="featured"
                    featured={true}
                    modalClick={this.openModal}
                />
            );
            break;
    }
    this.handleDrawerClose();
    this.setState({
        content: newContent
    })
};
```

I call the handleClick function like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.handleClick(MainMenuConstants.COMMERCIAL)}>
    <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon><AttachMoney /></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Commercial Projects"/>
    </ListItem>
</Button>
```

Again, I'm probably doing this all wrong. But what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of best practice tips.

1. You shouldn't store JSX elements in your state.  A JSX element is the result of doing something like `<ComplexCardGrid />`.  These should only be created and used while rendering your app.
2. Using random keys will force every component to continuously unmount and remount.  You need to figure out a proper way to make sure that keys are both unique and do not change between renders.  You can probably just use the array index for this, although that isn't quite best practice either.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll make sure to try and get better at those things :)